# What is the proper way of inserting records to tables with many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example I Have 3 tables:

**Batches**

| id | name | sku | eta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pk | str | str | date |

**order lines**

| id | order_id | amount | sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pk | int | str | str |

**allocations**

| id | batch_id | orderline_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk | fk to batches.id | fk to order_lines.id |

What is the correct way of filling up those tables?

Currently I'm doing it in a transaction like so:

```sql
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO batches (name, sku, eta) VALUES ('test1', 'BLUE CHAIR', null);
    INSERT INTO order_lines (order_id, amount, sku) VALUES (157, 140, 'BLUE CHAIR');
    INSERT INTO allocations (batch_id, orderline_id) SELECT MAX(b.id), MAX(ol.id) FROM batches b, order_lines ol;
COMMIT;
```

But I feel like doing the third insert with SELECT MAX(id) from another table is wrong? Wouldn't it cause a race conditions or data corruption if another client has inserted a new record while my query is being executed?
How to deal with m2m inserts using raw sql?

Comment: You can use a RETURNIG clause to get 
 Id of the inserted raw https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Comment: @Serg I did check RETURNING but unfortunatly my sqlite version is 3.34 which has no support for this clause, anyway, Is it correct statement that using `RETURNING` would be a right thing to do or usually inserting into m2m tables is done in some other way?

Comment: It can be done in your application code.

Comment: @forpas what if it's not an application side? What if it's done using stored procedures?

Comment: SQLite does not support stored procedures.

Comment: @forpas Nevertheless, question could be applied to any database

Comment: Then don't tag the question SQLite because you will not get the solutions that you want.

Comment: @forpas Now I have to say that i did not tag any programming language or said anything about application to get a suggestions about using an application-side code... If anything i'd just used an ORM without asking about raw sequel.

Comment: You have set the SQLite under your question. This implies, for anyone that sees your question, that you want a solution that works with SQLite specifically. If you are interested only in a general sql solution you should mention that in your question and remove the SQLite tag.

Comment: @forpas, thank you for suggestion, i've fixed those misleading inconveniences.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to Serg's proposal, of using the `RETURNING` clause, if the attributes combination used in the where clauses are unique and do not change (I assume that the `eta` should sooner or late be populated, potentially causing race conditions if transactions are not used).

```
INSERT INTO allocations (batch_id, orderline_id)
SELECT b.id, ol.id
FROM (SELECT id FROM batches WHERE name = 'test1' AND sku = 'BLUE CHAIR' AND eta IS NULL) b
  JOIN (SELECT id FROM order_lines WHERE order_id = 157 AND amount = 140 AND sku = 'BLUE CHAIR') ol ON 1 = 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that entires in `order_lines` are unique. I actually tried this solution yesterday